# Mock a Property Getter with Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, mocking, properties, rhino, getter

Here is the property "LoggerName" of a class "ConfigurationSection".

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets The LoggerName.
/// </summary>
[ConfigurationProperty("LoggerName", IsRequired = true)]
public string LoggerName
{
    get { return Convert.ToString(this["LoggerName"]); }
}
```

If I create a stub or a strict mock of this type, when this property gets called, it throws an exception.

I've tried to mock this property with code such as:

```
Expect.Call(configSection.LoggerName).Return("LOREMIPSUM");
```

and

```
configSection.Stub(x => x.LoggerName).Return("LOREMIPSUM");
```

But this code calls that property getter and throws an exception.

I've looked in various places and all the methods I've tried do the same thing.

Does anyone know anything that might help me?

Many thanks in advance.

Ryan

Answer (score 2):

For mocking classes with rhino, you'll have to mark the Property that you are mocking as `virtual`.

Can you try changing your property to this

```
public virtual string LoggerName
{
    get { return Convert.ToString(this["LoggerName"]); }
}
```

and see if you can get it to work?

Comment: Also, try extracting interface, something like interface ILog { string LoggerName {get;set}}

Comment: The other option is to switch to a mocking framework that can emit IL for mocking classes so you don't have to mark members virtual just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Denis [Mols](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) is and there are a few others.

Comment: From Moles site: throw new Y2KBugException() hahahhahaha
Very nice, didn't know about this framework